# Trying to toggle something and hide the toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

So I have this image placeholder acting as my toggle button, when I click the placeholder it should go away and show another content. But when .chrome is clicked it goes away but the switchScreen don't show up.

.chrome is acting as the button and trying to toggle switchScreen

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var switchScreen = ".home";

    $(".chrome").click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this).attr('rel');
        screenSwitcher('.' + clicked);
    });

    function screenSwitcher(switchScreen){
        $(".switchScreen").css('display', 'none');
        $(switchScreen).fadeIn('slow');
    }

    $(".chrome").click(function(){
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
    screenSwitcher(switchScreen);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code for one you have `$(".chrome").click(` two times you can combine these two into one function.  What you want to do is hide your `.swithScreen` when the page first loads you can do this in the document ready function.  Anyway look over this code It should help.

Html

```
<img class="chrome" rel="switchScreen" src="/plato/resources/images/delete.png" />

<p class="switchScreen">hoho</p>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".switchScreen").css('display', 'none');
   $(".chrome").click(function() {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
      var clicked = $(this).attr('rel');
      screenSwitcher('.' + clicked);
  });
  function screenSwitcher(switchScreen){
    $(switchScreen).fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BBpKV/2/

However this same functionality can be accomplished in much less code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".switchScreen").hide();
  $(".chrome").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".switchScreen").fadeIn('slow'); 
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BBpKV/4/

Comment: Thanks, been trying to figure solve it using if statements but no luck. Although the Jquery code is just similar to what I posted just sort of jumbled :/

thanks